# Why do some email software products block SSL certificates attached to a message?

Tags: tls, certificates, email

Whenever I have to share our public SSL certificate with our trading partners through email, I have to change the filename extension of the attached file (i.e. from “.cer” to “.txt”) to ensure it is delivered without issues. Why is it so? Where is the possible threat?

Comment: Maybe it's a very strict whitelist, and that extension just happens to not be in the whitelist? Or, they are concerned about the browser's default action resulting in the certificate being installed as a trusted CA.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you perhaps referring to [Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/blocked-attachments-in-outlook-434752e1-02d3-4e90-9124-8b81e49a8519) that is blocking `.cer`, `.crt` and `.der` without giving a specific reason per filetype? More file types were blocked on March 6th 2020, but [The Exchange Team](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/changes-to-file-types-blocked-in-outlook-on-the-web/ba-p/874451) doesn't give any more detailed reasoning than this (and many are wondering the same in the comment section):

> **Why are we making this change?**
>
> We’re always evaluating ways to improve security for our customers,
>   and so we took the time to audit the existing blocked file list and
>   update it to better reflect the file types we see as risks today.

Certificate attachments aren't blocked e.g. by [Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6590?hl=en), so it's not a universal practice.

The rationale might be to prevent scams asking to **install malicious root certificates**, although they have been quite rare on email attachments and mostly seen on [web pages](https://www.scmagazine.com/website-web-server-security/dont-install-that-security-certificate-its-a-malware-scam/). The consequences would be bad, as it would allow intercepting TLS, appearing as someone else etc.

However, I'm not sure whether this really is any good practice, as

- it requires more work when you actually need to send a certificate in an email.
- it is equally easy to circumvent for malicious purposes.
- all Microsoft Office documents are still allowed, having all kind of nasty macros.

Comment: The last bullet point isn't really applicable. Office has blocked/disabled Macros in documents opened from email/downloaded from the internet for 8 or so years.

Comment: The article that you mentioned does not report about web pages that install malicious root certificates, it actually installs a malware executable (pretending to install certificates). See the referenced blog post: https://securelist.com/mokes-and-buerak-distributed-under-the-guise-of-security-certificates/96324/